# android how to align radio-buttons inside radio group?

Tags: android, xml, radio-button, radio-group

I have something like a table in my activity( I used vertical + horizontal linear layouts to make this table), in this table I have buttons, edit texts, and radio buttons. I need to align radio-buttons inside radiogroup correspondingly to all table. But currently radio-buttons looks like shifted to left.

I played  with gravity of each radio button, with gravity of radio-group and it didn't help.

Here is the code of 2 last horizontal linear layouts. I need to align radio-buttons to be centered like editText.

```
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="6">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageQuest"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/quest1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:digits="0123456789-"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="3"
                android:hint="0"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/quest2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:digits="0123456789-"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="3"
                android:hint="0"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/quest3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:digits="0123456789-"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="3"
                android:hint="0"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/quest4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:digits="0123456789-"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="3"
                android:hint="0"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/quest5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:digits="0123456789-"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="3"
                android:hint="0"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="6">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageLongestWay"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/RadioGroup"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="5">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </RadioGroup>


        </LinearLayout>
```

Here is screenshot:
[Radio-buttons are not aligned inside radio-group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZl3v.png)

Comment: apply  android:gravity="center" to the linearlayout containing radiobutton

Comment: RadioGroup inherits from LinearLayout. Therefore, you can use **weights** as you would in a LinearLayout.

Comment: android:gravity="center" to the linearlayout containing radiobutton -> didn't help

Comment: RadioGroup inherits from LinearLayout. Therefore, you can use weights as you would in a LinearLayout. – Rotwang yesterday -> didn't help either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create custom `RadioButton` in drawable:

```
<RadioButton
      android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="50dip"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:button="@android:color/transparent"
      android:drawableLeft="@drawable/custom_radio_button"/>
```

custom_radio_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checked_radio_button" android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_uncheked_radio_button" android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

Comment: It was good attempt, custom radio-button looks bigger, but anyway it is not aligned as I want, it's still shifted to left side

Comment: you need to add images in drawable using image Asset in will create images for hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi.

Comment: Nope, image Asset here is unnecessary. Your first advise about custom radio-button was very good. Almost right. Just need to replace "android:drawableLeft=" to "android:drawableTop=" and now it is aligned well.

Comment: Image Asset solution for radio button looks bigger, not to aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [S.B.K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5978411/s-b-k) for advise, we need to use custom radio button image. And use "android:drawableTop="

so
1) download 2 images from internet. One for checked radio, one for unchecked. 
2) Put them to drawable folder in your project
3) create custom_radio_button.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checked_radio_button" android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="false" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_uncheked_radio_button" android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="false" />
```

4) change your radiobutton parameters to

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:button="@android:color/transparent"
android:drawableTop="@drawable/custom_radio_button"/>
```